# Open a panel on a link button click (Panel contains checkbox list)

Tags: c#, jquery, gridview, panel, checkboxlist

I seriously need some help here. I have grid view with some columns. one of the column in gridview is a linkbutton. The panel contains a preloaded checkbolist values and i want to open the panel on click of gridview link button using Jquery. once the panel is opened on a link button click i want to check the checkboxes for that particular offer row and on click of "OK" button i want to save back the checked columns to gridview hidden column. Please see the screenshot and code below and help me in figuring this out. Please note that i cannot use AJAX controls due to restrictions on our server.

[image]

// Panel Code

```
<asp:Panel ID="plnClone" runat="server" Width="150px" Style="border: 1 double #000000;">
                                    <table width="98%" style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align: left;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="250px" ScrollBars="Vertical">
                                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklistReferralCodes" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfdCloneOffer" runat="server" />
                                <input type="button" id="OkClone" value="Ok" />
                                <input type="button" id="CancelClone" value="Cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use JQuery dialog [link here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
Add your panel to  and use opening function on onclientclick link button event.
Hope this helps.